# Getting MapBox geolocation coordinates into a variable

Tags: routes, geolocation, gps, mapbox

I created a map with a couple of markers and able to geolocate the user, that part is already done but I can't seem to find how to actually get the result of geolocating the user, all I get is the button to toggle it, but whatever goes on seems to be inside Mapbox itself.
Any idea on how I can save the result of the user location to a variable so I can use it as a route starting point (using Mapbox Directions API).
Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl();

map.addControl(geolocate);

geolocate.on('geolocate', function(e) {
      var lon = e.coords.longitude;
      var lat = e.coords.latitude
      var position = [lon, lat];
      console.log(position);
});
```

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geolocatecontrol.event:geolocate